# How can I correctly execute JSP code to retrieve a value from the HttpSession into a JavaScript function?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, session, servlets

I am working on a very old legacy Java web application that is based on HttpServlet and I have the following problem trying to running JSP code into a JavaScript function.

So, into a JSP page I found this JavaScript function that give me some problem:

```
function rifiuta() {

    document.getElementById('notaRifiuto').value = document.getElementById('myRejectNote').value;

    my_pkcoda = '<%=((request.getSession().getAttribute("doc_num")!=null?((String)request.getSession().getAttribute("doc_num")).trim():""))%>';

    document.getElementById(my_pkcoda).checked = true;
    checkRifiuta();
}
```

This is very simple:

It is declared a ** my_pkcoda** that try to be initialized with a value obtained from the **HttpSession** that is neamed **doc_num**, this is done by:

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("doc_num")
```

I am pretty sure that this value is into the **HttpSession** because I put it into the session by (into the class that implement my **HttpServlet**:

```
req.getSession().setAttribute("doc_num", req.getParameter("pk"));
```

and after do this operation I check if it is correctly putted into the session using the debugger and it is ok, it is into the session.

The problem is that when into my JSP page the **rifiuta()** JavaScript function is performed, when it try to execute this statment:

```
my_pkcoda = '<%=((request.getSession().getAttribute("doc_num")!=null?((String)request.getSession().getAttribute("doc_num")).trim():""))%>';
```

I obtain that the **my_pkcoda** value is null.

What could be the problem?  What am I missing?

Tnx

Comment: Can you try `console.log('<%=((request.getSession().getAttribute("doc_num")!=null?((String)request.getSession().getAttribute("doc_num")).trim():""))%>') ` and see what is shown in the javascript console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP scriptlet tags get evaluated only once when the web page is loaded from the server. The value of that scriptlet expression gets pasted in your JS function as a text the first time when the page is loaded from server.

On each call of the JS function `rifiuta` that value will not get loaded from the session.

So, in case you are calling rifiuta on a button click, you will not get the latest value of `doc_num` attribute from session.